# Recurrence relation for the partial sum of an alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, recurrence-relations

If $z \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $p_{z,n}$ is the number of sequences, $a_1, \dots, a_n$ of size $n$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, so that for $0 \leq j \leq n$: $$0 \leq \sum_{i=1}^j (-1)^{i-1}a_i \leq z$$

I need to find a recurrence relation for $p_{z,n}$ and calculate $p_{4,4}$.

I am unable to formulate an equation for $a_n$ that could help me simplify a relation for this partial sum of an alternating series.

Comment: Is there a bound on the $a_i$? If not, once you get the sum between $y$ and $z$ you can get an arbitrary number of terms using $m, -(m+1), m+3, -(m+2)$ which leaves the sum unchanged.

Comment: I can't see a way to express $p_{y,z,n}$ directly in terms of $p_{y,z,n-1}$, as whether the next term is valid would depend on what $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{i-1} a_i$ is. You might have to split $p_{y,z,n}$ up into parts to get a recurrence, e.g. $p_{y,z,n,m}$ is the no. of sequences satisfying the same conditions, but with $m = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{i-1} a_i$. Then you could express $p_{y,z,n} = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} p_{y,z,n,m}$.

Comment: No. That totals -2. I chose mine to total zero so an arbitrarily large number of terms would leave the sum unchanged. just choose a value of m at least 4 larger for the new set.

Comment: The computation imposes alternating signs on the sum.

Comment: Doesn't say it has to be monotonic.

Comment: @martycohen: $j$ is *arbitrary* here (which implies a bound on your $m$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recurrence is a bit complicated, but at least *it works better than the brute-force* enumeration...

For $\bar{a}=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $1\leqslant j\leqslant n$, let's denote $\sum_{i=1}^{j}(-1)^{i-1}a_i$ by $s_j(\bar{a})$. Thus, $$p_{z,n}=\#P_{z,n},\quad P_{z,n}:=\{\bar{a}\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}^{n} : 0\leqslant s_j(\bar{a})\leqslant z\text{ for all }1\leqslant j\leqslant n\}.$$ Suppose $n>1$. For an element $\bar{a}$ of $P_{z,n}$, either $s_j(\bar{a})>0$ for all $1\leqslant j\leqslant n$ (then we must have $a_1>1$, and if we replace $a_1$ by $a_1-1$, we obtain an element of $P_{z-1,n}$; this is one-to-one, hence there are $p_{z-1,n}$ such elements), or $s_j(\bar{a})=0$ for some $j$ (which is clearly even); let $2d$ be the smallest such $j$. Since $s_{2d}(\bar{a})=0$, the parts $(a_1,\ldots a_{2d})$ and $(a_{2d+1},\ldots,a_n)$ can be formed (hence counted) independently.

The number of suitable parts $(a_{2d+1},\ldots,a_n)$ is clearly $p_{z,n-2d}$. As for $(a_1,\ldots,a_{2d})$, we must have $a_{2d}=s_{2d-1}(\bar{a})$ and $s_j(\bar{a})>0$ for $0<j<2d$. This is similar to the above, but here we must distinguish $d=1$ (when the number of parts is $p_{z,2d-1}=p_{z,1}=z$) and $d>1$ (when it is again $p_{z\color{red}{-1},2d-1}$).

With boundary cases $p_{z,1}=z$, $p_{1,n}=p_{z,0}=1$ (the last one to handle the case $2d=n$), the recurrence is $$\bbox[5pt,border:2pt solid]{p_{z,n}=p_{z-1,n}+zp_{z,n-2}+\sum_{d=2}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}p_{z-1,2d-1}p_{z,n-2d}.}\qquad(z,n>1)$$

And here is a table of $p_{z,n}$ for $1\leqslant z,n\leqslant 9$:
$$\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrrr}
n=\to&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
z=1& 1&  1&   1&    1&     1&      1&      1&       1&        1\\
z=2& 2&  3&   5&    8&    13&     21&     34&      55&       89\\
z=3& 3&  6&  14&   31&    70&    157&    353&     793&     1782\\
z=4& 4& 10&  30& \color{blue}{85}&   246&    707&   2037&    5864&    16886\\
z=5& 5& 15&  55&  190&   671&   2353&   8272&   29056&   102091\\
z=6& 6& 21&  91&  371&  1547&   6405&  26585&  110254&   457379\\
z=7& 7& 28& 140&  658&  3164&  15106&  72302&  345775&  1654092\\
z=8& 8& 36& 204& 1086&  5916&  31998& 173502&  940005&  5094220\\
z=9& 9& 45& 285& 1695& 10317&  62349& 377739& 2286648& 13846117\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: (I see that each row satisfies a linear recurrence of order $z$, and there's an interesting pattern...)